# How can I set the default 'orderby' and 'order' parameters for a REST API call?

Tags: rest-api, order, menu-order

I have added 'menu_order' to the available orderby methods by using the [Simple Custom Post Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/) plugin and by following the instructions in [this blog post](https://www.timrosswebdevelopment.com/wordpress-rest-api-post-order/), which provides the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The filter is named rest_{post_type}_collection_params. So you need to hook a new filter for each 
 * of the custom post types you need to sort.
 * @link https://www.timrosswebdevelopment.com/wordpress-rest-api-post-order/
 */

// This enables the orderby=menu_order for Posts
add_filter( 'rest_post_collection_params', 'filter_add_rest_orderby_params', 10, 1 );
// And this for a custom post type called 'portfolio'
add_filter( 'rest_portfolio_collection_params', 'filter_add_rest_orderby_params', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Add menu_order to the list of permitted orderby values
 */
function filter_add_rest_orderby_params( $params ) {
    $params['orderby']['enum'][] = 'menu_order';
    return $params;
}
```

I have tacked that code onto a locally developed site-specific plugin. This works fine and I can get the posts in the order I want using:

`.../wp-json/wp/v2/posts&order=asc&orderby=menu_order`

How can I make that the default so that

`.../wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

returns the posts in the same order as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following addition the above code changes the default for the 'portfolio' post type.

```
add_filter( 'rest_portfolio_collection_params','filter_add_rest_orderby_params', 10, 2 );

function filter_add_rest_orderby_params( $params, $post_type  ) {
$params['orderby']['enum'][] = 'menu_order';
if ( $post_type->name === 'portfolio' ) {
    $params['orderby']['default'] = 'menu_order';
    $params['order']['default'] = 'asc';
}
return $params;
```